# Comparing "key" values in javascript tuples

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using associative array to create json objects, serialize and send them to a third party:

```
var MSG = {}
MSG["SESSION_START"] = 0x0000;
MSG["DONE"]          = 0x0001;

var session_id = gen_rand_no();
var msg_tuple = {MSG["SESSION_START"] : session_id};
var json_msg_tuple = JSON.stringify(msg_tuple);

send(json_msg_tuple);
```

The party would normally reply with an acknowledgement message in a form of a serialized JSON object:

```
var serialized_json = recv();
var json_obj = JSON.parse(serialized_json);
```

How can I check if the first element in the JSON object is corresponding to the **MSG["DONE"]** value?

In the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784921/how-to-retrieve-key-values-in-javascript) question, it is assumed that the JSON object has a given set of attributes until the nested ones are iterated over.

Comment: Probable dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909003/javascript-getting-the-first-index-of-an-object

Comment: I don't think `{MSG["SESSION_START"] : session_id}` is valid JavaScript.

Comment: First of all, you're just using JavaScript objects. JSON is a format for strings. Because of that I think you're overthinking this. Just set a breakpoint and inspect what `json_obj` has on it. You can probably just use `json_obj['DONE']`...

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat I only need a unique mapping between a descriptive string message and a 2 byte integer value.

Comment: @Sebi: Yeah, but your `msg_tuple` is a syntax error.

Comment: So, what *exactly* is in `json_obj`?  What does `console.log(json_obj)` show you?

Comment: It's a json obj. of a serialized tuple of the form <int,byte[]>. What is wrong with the syntax of the tuple assignment?

Comment: It shows a syntax error at the tuple assignment.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "tuples", per se.  Also you can use `MSG.SESSION_START` instead of `MSG["SESSION_START"]`.

Comment: In order to use a *variable* value as a key, you need to do:  `var msg_tuple = {};  msg_tuple[MSG["SESSION_START"]] = session_id;`.  In ES6, however, you can do: `var msg_tuple = {[MSG["SESSION_START"]]: session_id};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in JavaScript have no "key order" so there is no such thing as a "first element".

With that in mind, the following two options exist for testing if the key exists:

```
if( MSG['DONE'] in json_obj)
// or...
if( json_obj.hasOwnProperty(MSG['DONE']))
```

Comment: Although, if you for some reason don't know the name of the key you could do this: `Object.keys(json_obj)[0]`

Comment: What would be the behavior if the second item in the tuple would also have  the value 0x0000 and the first one a distinct value?

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers (IE9+, FF4+, Chrome5+, Opera12+, Safari5+) you could use the built in Object.keys method:

```
var keys = Object.keys(json_obj);
if (json_obj[keys[0]] === MSG["DONE"]) { ... }
```

Does this answer your question? Is it the value of the first json_obj attribute that you want to compare to the value of MSG["DONE"]? Or did I misread your question?

P.S. I tried the Object.keys() method and it returns the keys in the order they are listed in the object, but I am not sure if this is guaranteed.